# How can I simply link two view controllers up with a page control. (Swift iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers with an id of firstController and secondController. I want to be able to slide between them using a page controller but I don't know how to do this. I have looked at tutorials but they are for making little tutorial bits at the start of your apps not the actual app.

So how would I link them up so that I can swipe between them?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code wich you need. I also searched very long to find this. It works very fine. Maybe you want to change "as?" to "as!" to force a downcast of the destination ViewControllers, but don't do it if you are planning a segue later.

```
    import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    var myViewControllers = Array(count: 4, repeatedValue:UIViewController())

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        let pvc = segue.destinationViewController as? UIPageViewController

        pvc?.dataSource = self

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

        var vc0 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Infoseite")  as! UIViewController
        var vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Anmeldung2") as! UIViewController
        var vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Anmeldung3") as! UIViewController
        var vc3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Anmeldung4") as! UIViewController


        storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Anmeldung4")

        self.myViewControllers = [ vc0, vc1, vc2, vc3]

        pvc?.setViewControllers([myViewControllers[1]], direction:.Forward, animated:false, completion:nil)

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!+1
        if currentIndex >= self.myViewControllers.count {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers[currentIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!-1
        if currentIndex < 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers[currentIndex]
    }
```

You can simply delete vc3 and vc4. You only have to watch out that every vc3 and vc4 is deleted and that you write "Array(count: 2,"...

Answer (score 1):

Use a gesture recognizer to see when the user has swiped a direction...

Won't let me post images, so take a look [here](http://s23.postimg.org/jyrlsniob/Screen_Shot_2015_07_10_at_00_23_07.png).

Then change the view controller using something like this...

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController

self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

You could also use a segue of course. ([performSegueWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSeguePerforming/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) method)

Comment: Yes but that isn't the effect I am trying to get. With that, the user swipes, then the view controller comes up from the bottom, I need to use a page controller so it swipes as the user is swiping.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Page-Based application template that Xcode provides?